# Showing a non-child view in tabBar ... android

Tags: android, view, android-tabhost

I have 3 tabs in a tab bar. On top of the tap bar, I have a button. I want to be able to press the button and change the view, without removing the tab bar. I want to set clear the current tab selection of the tab bar, and want another activity to show, without hiding the tab bar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your code really looks like there isn't much help we can give you other than some links to some methods that sound like they might help you out...

Take a look at these methods on the ViewGroup class:

1. [ViewGroup.RemoveView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29)
2. [ViewGroup.RemoveViewAt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewAt%28int%29)

Comment: I have not used ViewGroup, because I think it is deprecated. So what I have done is that I load a different view by setContentView(), and initialize everything according to the new view. But that should not have anything to do with this task I guess.

Comment: What makes you think that ViewGroup is deprecated?  It is the parent class for any layout that has more than one child... It is not deprecated.  If you have a LinearLayout (whose parent class is ViewGroup) you can do this: lyt.RemoveViewAt(0) to remove the first view in the layout